# Visual Studio custom build-generated file included by a .cpp

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a custom build rule on a data file which generates a header file. The custom build rule works fine (runs when the data is changed and does not run when it is not, as I would expect it to).

However, this generated header file is included by a `.cpp` file which is compiled using the default C++ compiler. When the header is generated and there are no changes in the `.cpp` itself, the build system will not compile it. I have to build twice, once to generate the header file and then once more for the build system to notice and rebuild the `.cpp` as well (the generated header has the current date/time so there are no problems there, it just seems that Visual Studio makes all the checks before starting the build).

Not a major issue but it gets annoying after a while. It is also error-prone. Is there a way to either expedite the custom build rule so that it would run before Visual Studio checks the dependences of the `.cpp` files or maybe to run the build twice? There may be several files using this custom build rule so using a pre-build step to build them all would get messy.

I'm using VS 2008 if that makes any difference. The custom build rule has the "Outputs" field correctly filled in so it has the information about the files the custom build generates.

Comment: Are you generating your .hpp fine in a pre-build event?

Comment: Try to create a different proyect with the data file and the custom build rule that generate the .h and then reference this new proyect from your current one.

Comment: @Jepessen No, not a pre-build  event. Custom build rule on a "regular" source file.

Comment: @Min yeah, that actually does the job. I create a new project of type `Utility` (so that it does not expect it to produce an .exe) and set a dependency. Then the project build order imposes waiting. Nicely done!